# Is there a way to count number of documents in a collection i Firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

```
        db.collectionGroup('rating').where('rating','==',5).get().then(function (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
            var fivestarRatings = doc.data().rating;
            console.log(fivestarRatings)
        });
    });
```

This returns 5 twice, because I have a subcollection named 'rating' and two documents in that collection contains "5". Basically I want to count how many documents that contains a sertain value. In this case I want it to show "2" because there are two documents in "rating" that contains "5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `querySnapshot` is a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) type object.  You can see from the linked API documentation that you can call its size() method to count the documents in the result set.

```
const size = querySnapshot.size()
```